# How to add a new dynamic value(which is not there in input) to logstash output?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

My input has timestamp in the format of Apr20 14:59:41248 Dataxyz. 
Now in my output i need the timestamp in the below format:
**Day Month Monthday Hour:Minute:Second Year DataXYZ **. I was able to remove the timestamp from the input. But I am not quite sure how to add the new timestamp.

I matched the message using grok while receiving the input:
 `match => ["message","%{WORD:word} %{TIME:time} %{GREEDYDATA:content}"]`

I tried using mutate add_field.but was not successful in adding the value of the DAY. `add_field => [ "timestamp","%{DAY}"]`.I got the output as the word ´DAY´ and not the value of DAY. Can someone please throw some light on what is being missed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to grok it out into the individual named fields, and then you can reference those fields in add_field.

So your grok would start like this:

```
%{MONTH:month}%{MONTHDAY:mday}
```

And then you can put them back together like this:

```
mutate {
    add_field => {
        "newField" => "%{mday} %{month}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respose Alain. But i have only Apr20 14:59:41248 in my input. In my output I need to add Day Month Monthday Hour:Minute:Second Year  . DAY is not input. Also i do not know how to split Apr20 into month and monthday since it is coming together. There is no space between Apr and 20.That is the reason I had to grok it into a WORD.Please help.

Comment: Since %{MONTH} is defined to require whitespace, make your own version of it (e.g. %{MONTHNOSPACES}) that doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with my answer, I think this very helpful to you.

```
grok { 
  match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{NUMBER:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{JAVACLASS:class} - %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" } 
}

if "Exception" in [msg] {
 mutate {
  add_field => { "msg_error" => "%{msg}" }
}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how this answer is helping my question. I need to know how to grok **Apr20 ** (without space) and change that to **Day Month Monthday** format

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom grok patterns to extract/rename fields.

[image]

You can extract other fields similarly and rearrange/play arounnd with them in mutate filter. Refer to [Custom Patterns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns) for more information.